# Syntax Error in the version info when trying to run a module in Python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x

I am new, like still have the plastic wrapping on me, new, to programming anything much less Python but I am trying to learn.  My first experience is baffling already.  I typed out some get to know the program code and as I was doing it everything was fine within the shell, blah blah.  I saved and opened it again to watch it run. However when I chose run module is gave me a syntax error in the part of the program I didn't even write.

The 2 in "Python 3.2" is red and will not run.

**Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 20 2011, 21:29:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.**

Tried to ask in class and just got a lecture about how I was behind.  Someone else pointed me here and said this was the place, if I was going to learn programming I needed to get to know the site anyway!

So how can I check the work if I cannot run it? Am I missing a vital piece of the puzzle?

Assistance would be wonderful.

These were my steps:

- Followed instructions on the code, watched as it draw as I was
  adding.
- Saved closed everything.
- Reopened > chose file option: open> found file opened it
- Chose run option> run module
- Nothing happened,"invalid syntax"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the file you are trying to run is simply a log of everything that you typed and that was printed while you typed; the first line being the version info of the python you are running, which is definitely not executable code, hence the "invalid syntax" error.

What you'll want to do is open an empty text file, enter in all the code again, save it as a `somefile.py` (a better name, obviously ;) and then open that in the `run` menu.

Alternatively, you could open the file you have already and remove all the lines that are not the code you had typed in.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Will try that!